# Draw a circle in canvas manually pixel by pixel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to do some complicated effect, and to do it i have to break it down into its components, upon which i can build on and hopefully they will come together.

Now to make a circle in canvas is easy. But i want to make it myself. So I want to write a function that would be given a point that's center, radius, and then it will draw a circle with 1 px stroke width.

How would i go about it? If i look at from math perspective, what comes to mind is use circle distance formula and increment by small values, like .3 degrees, and make a dot at circumference. But if my circle is too small, like 2 px radius. Then it will waste lot of time drawing that won't matter, and if it's big enough you will see spaces between dots.

so i want my circle drawing function to draw a

- dot if radius is 1px.
- 4 dots around the center if radius is 2px.
- ..and so on.
- also if this gonna make my circle look rigid, i want there to be antialiasing too :D

I suppose once i know how to make outline filling it in won't be a problem..all i'd've to do is reduce the radius and keep drawing until radius is 1px.

Comment: You could calculate the circumference and then decide how many points you want do draw. Check out this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: i found this, i think it's revelant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: lol talk about coincidence

Comment: if you understand what it's saying then can you tell me if i have radius how would i go finding points or angles to draw points at?

Comment: about "all i'd've to do is reduce the radius and keep drawing until radius is 1px.": To draw a filled circle you just need to loop from -radius to +radius on x and y, and if the pythagoras between the center and actual x/y is smaller than radius, then draw the pixel. this is less calculating and faster i think. You also could draw the outline with this approach if you just draw if the pythagoras - radius is between -0.5 and +0.5

Comment: If you don't understand the wikipedia-article just check out the example in C#, you can rebuild it directly in javascript with slight changes (i.e. remove "int", replace "public static void" with "function", ...)

Comment: I don't think the midpoint algorithm will help here. It's all about the efficient drawing of complete circles by progressively choosing a pixel adjacent to the one just drawn. The OP appears to want "sparse" circles in which pixels are not necessarily adjacent.

Comment: I was trying to make a lens zoom effect to add to the game i am trying to make where if you touch circle it explodes and creates shockwave that distorts everything. But i feel like i am the first man to do ever attempt it, as i don't find things on google that can help me. 
Level 1 zoom: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/71tfukjf/3/ ....

level 2... looked like it was going to work: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/71tfukjf/4/ ....
....Level 3: Not working as expected...lens zoom (fish eye) even for box didn't work :http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/71tfukjf/5/

Comment: basically i've been trying to make this effect http://www.flash-filter.net/lens-effect-online-demo.phtml

Comment: and someone made it in canvas somehow... http://www.soundstep.com/blog/2012/04/25/javascript-displacement-mapping/

Comment: @Roamer-1888 btw you got what i was saying..

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, I think I see what you are trying to achieve but am finding it difficult to relate the lens effect to the question. You're clearly deeply into this and must be at another level of understanding.

Comment: the reason i thought i need to know how to make a circle manually was so i could layout the zoomed in pixels, my plan was to read the canvas data, apply zoom function on data which also i have to figure out, then once i have modified data print it. And since lens are round, the printed result should contain a circle. i've found a way, to draw in circle without drawing circle manually, that is too draw circle using api, then clip it. But in tutorial above which displacement filter is what i would have prefered, as i think it give more flexibility. But i don't understand that.

Comment: I was able to make what i wanted using clip method, even though the trick is basically brute force kind and performance is really bad. It does work exactly i wanted... http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/71tfukjf/11/show/

Comment: In my method, if the radius is 30px, and zoom level 3. Then i divide zoom to 30. then make 30 screenshot of canvas each little shorter and more zoomed in. Then lay those 30 layers onto each other.

Comment: @Muhammad, that's a nice effect though, as you say, performance could be better. I managed to make a straightforward fisheye effect [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hed2fv15/) with reasonable performance but it doesn't throb.

Comment: I COULDN'T BE MORE IMPRESSED. First you understood my code, this IS what i wanted. Throbbing isn't even important. you should definitely, 100% write a blog post about it. I will subscribe to it for life. 
I have trouble understanding \\we are inside the circle..section. The thought of just copying the square as is and then mathematically worrying about circle did cross my mind, however.

Comment: @Muhammad, OK I didn't realise I had gotten so close to your final requirement. I can't take all the credit - everything is based on your code, which was very well organised, and some fisheye code in Java that I found on the web. All I did was translate Java to Javascript and merge with your code. TBH, I only understand enough to have done the integration. I haven't tried to analyse every line. Anyways, after some tidying, I will post everything as an answer.

Comment: yea thanks..ill wait..i just couldn't guess how zoom in effect is achieved. And yes now i put everything into very appropriately named function for more and more  to serve as communication checkpoint. Finding a function that does one thing is easier than even comments with comments you still can access variable 50 lines above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've re-factored my earlier code as a jQuery plugin named "canvasLens". It accepts a bunch of options to control things like image src, lens size and border color. You can even choose between two different lens effects, "fisheye" or "scaledSquare".

I've tried to make it as self-explanatory as possible with a header block and plenty of other comments.

```
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2014 Roamer-1888
 *  "canvasLens"
 *  a jQuery plugin for a lens effect on one or more HTML5 canvases
 *  by Roamer-1888, 2014-11-09
 *  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3478010/roamer-1888
 * 
 *  Written in response to aa question by Muhammad Umer, here
 *      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793321/
 * 
 *  Invoke on a canvas element as follows
 *  $("#canvas").lens({
 *    imgSrc: 'path/to/image',
 *    imgCrossOrigin: '' | 'anonymous' | 'use-credentials', //[1]
 *    drawImageCoords: [ //[2]
 *      0, 0, //(sx,st) Source image sub-rectangle Left,Top.
 *      1350, 788, //(sw/sh) Source image sub-rectangle Width,Height.
 *      0, 0, //(dx/dy) Destination Left,Top.
 *      800, 467 //(dw/dh) Destination image sub-rectangle Width,Height.
 *    ], 
 *    effect: 'fisheye' | 'scaledSquare',
 *    scale: 2 //currently affects only 'scaledSquare'
 *    size: 100, //diameter/side-length of the lens in pixels
 *    hideCursor: true | false,
 *    border: [0, 0, 0, 255] //[r,g,b,alpha] (base-10) | 'none'
 *  });
 * 
 * Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7z6by3o3/1/
 * 
 * Further reading :
 * [1] imgCrossOrigin - 
 *     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes
 * [2] drawImageCoords -
 *     https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D
 * 
 * Licence: MIT - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License
 * 
 * Please keep this header block intact, with amendments 
 * to reflect any changes made to the code.
 * 
 */
(function($){
    // *******************************
    // ***** Start: Private vars *****
    // *******************************
    var pluginName = 'canvasLens';
    // *****************************
    // ***** Fin: Private vars *****
    // *****************************

    // **********************************
    // ***** Start: Private Methods *****
    // **********************************
    // Note that in all private methods,
    // `this` is the canvas on which 
    // the plugin is invoked.
    // Most private methods are called 
    // with `methodName.call(this)`.
    // **********************************
    function animate() {
        var data = $(this).data(pluginName);
        if(data) {
            draw.call(this);
            requestAnimationFrame(animate.bind(this));
        }
    }
    function draw() {
        var data = $(this).data(pluginName);
        data.ctx.drawImage(data.m_can, 0, 0);
        if(data.showLens) {
            if(data.settings.effect == 'scaledSquare') {
                scaledSquare.call(this);
            } else {
                fisheye.call(this);
            }
        }
    }
    function putBg() {
        var data = $(this).data(pluginName);
        data.m_ctx.drawImage.apply(data.m_ctx, [data.img].concat(data.settings.drawImageCoords));
    }
    function scaledSquare() {
        var data = $(this).data(pluginName),
            xt = data.settings.scale,
            h = data.settings.size;
        data.ctx.drawImage(data.m_can,
            data.mouse.x - h/xt/2, data.mouse.y - h/xt/2, //sx,st Source image sub-rectangle Left,Top coordinates.
            h/xt, h/xt, //sw/sh Source image sub-rectangle Width,Height.
            data.mouse.x - h/2, data.mouse.y - h/2, //dx/dy Destination Left,Top coordinates.
            h, h //dw/dh The Width,Height to draw the image in the destination canvas.
        );
    }
    function fisheye() {
        var data = $(this).data(pluginName),
            d = data.settings.size,
            mx = data.mouse.x, my = data.mouse.y,
            srcpixels = data.m_ctx.getImageData(mx - d/2, my - d/2, d, d);
        fisheyeTransform.call(this, srcpixels.data, data.xpixels.data, d, d);
        data.ctx.putImageData(data.xpixels, mx - d/2, my - d/2);
    }
    function fisheyeTransform(srcData, xData, w, h) {
        /*
         *    Fish eye effect (barrel distortion)
         *    *** adapted from ***
         *    tejopa, 2012-04-29
         *    http://popscan.blogspot.co.ke/2012/04/fisheye-lens-equation-simple-fisheye.html
         */
        var data = $(this).data(pluginName),
            y, x, ny, nx, ny2, nx2, r, nr, theta, nxn, nyn, x2, y2, pos, srcpos;
        for (var y=0; y<h; y++) { // for each row
            var ny = ((2 * y) / h) - 1; // normalize y coordinate to -1 ... 1
            ny2 = ny * ny; // pre calculate ny*ny
            for (x=0; x<w; x++) { // for each column
                pos = 4 * (y * w + x);
                nx = ((2 * x) / w) - 1; // normalize x coordinate to -1 ... 1
                nx2 = nx * nx; // pre calculate nx*nx
                r = Math.sqrt(nx2 + ny2); // calculate distance from center (0,0)
                if(r > 1) {
                    /* 1-to-1 pixel mapping outside the circle */
                    /* An improvement would be to make this area transparent. ?How? */
                    xData[pos+0] = srcData[pos+0];//red
                    xData[pos+1] = srcData[pos+1];//green
                    xData[pos+2] = srcData[pos+2];//blue
                    xData[pos+3] = srcData[pos+3];//alpha
                }
                else if(data.settings.border && data.settings.border !== 'none' && r > (1-3/w) && r < 1) { // circular border around fisheye
                    xData[pos+0] = data.settings.border[0];//red
                    xData[pos+1] = data.settings.border[1];//green
                    xData[pos+2] = data.settings.border[2];//blue
                    xData[pos+3] = data.settings.border[3];//alpha
                }
                else if (0<=r && r<=1) { // we are inside the circle, let's do a fisheye transform on this pixel
                    nr = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(r,2));
                    nr = (r + (1 - nr)) / 2; // new distance is between 0 ... 1
                    if (nr<=1) { // discard radius greater than 1.0
                        theta = Math.atan2(ny, nx); // calculate the angle for polar coordinates
                        nxn = nr * Math.cos(theta); // calculate new x position with new distance in same angle
                        nyn = nr * Math.sin(theta); // calculate new y position with new distance in same angle
                        x2 = Math.floor(((nxn + 1) * w) / 2); // map from -1 ... 1 to image coordinates
                        y2 = Math.floor(((nyn + 1) * h) / 2); // map from -1 ... 1 to image coordinates
                        srcpos = Math.floor(4 * (y2 * w + x2));
                        if (pos >= 0 && srcpos >= 0 && (pos+3) < xData.length && (srcpos+3) < srcData.length) { // make sure that position stays within arrays
                            /* get new pixel (x2,y2) and put it to target array at (x,y) */
                            xData[pos+0] = srcData[srcpos+0];//red
                            xData[pos+1] = srcData[srcpos+1];//green
                            xData[pos+2] = srcData[srcpos+2];//blue
                            xData[pos+3] = srcData[srcpos+3];//alpha
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ********************************
    // ***** Fin: Private methods *****
    // ********************************

    // *********************************
    // ***** Start: Public Methods *****
    // *********************************
    var methods = {
        'init': function(options) {
            //"this" is a jquery object on which this plugin has been invoked.
            return this.each(function(index) {
                var can = this,
                    $this = $(this);
                var data = $this.data(pluginName);
                if (!data) { // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                    data = {
                        target: $this,
                        showLens: false,
                        mouse: {x:0, y:0}
                    };
                    $this.data(pluginName, data);

                    var settings = {
                        imgSrc: '',
                        imgCrossOrigin: '',
                        drawImageCoords: [
                            0, 0, //sx,st Source image sub-rectangle Left,Top coordinates.
                            500, 500, //sw/sh Source image sub-rectangle Width,Height.
                            0, 0, //dx/dy Destination Left,Top coordinates.
                            500, 500 //(dw/dh) Destination image sub-rectangle Width,Height.
                        ],
                        effect: 'fisheye',
                        scale: 2,
                        size: 100,
                        border: [0, 0, 0, 255], //[r,g,b,alpha] base-10
                        hideCursor: false
                    };
                    if(options) {
                        $.extend(true, settings, options);
                    }
                    data.settings = settings;

                    if(settings.hideCursor) {
                        data.originalCursor = $this.css('cursor');
                        $this.css('cursor', 'none');
                    }

                    $this.on('mouseenter.'+pluginName, function(e) {
                        data.showLens = true;
                    }).on('mousemove.'+pluginName, function(e) {
                        data.mouse.x = e.offsetX;
                        data.mouse.y = e.offsetY;
                    }).on('mouseleave.'+pluginName, function(e) {
                        data.showLens = false;
                    });
                    data.m_can = $("<canvas>").attr({
                        'width': can.width,
                        'height': can.height
                    })[0];
                    data.ctx = can.getContext("2d"); // lens effect
                    data.m_ctx = data.m_can.getContext('2d'); // background image
                    data.xpixels = data.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, settings.size, settings.size);
                    data.img = new Image();
                    data.img.onload = function() {
                        putBg.call(can);
                        animate.call(can);
                    };
                    data.img.crossOrigin = settings.imgCrossOrigin;
                    data.img.src = settings.imgSrc;
                }
            });
        },
        'destroy': function() {
            return this.each(function(index) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data(pluginName);
                $this.off('mouseenter.'+pluginName)
                    .off('mousemove.'+pluginName)
                    .off('mouseleave.'+pluginName);
                if(data && data.originalCursor) {
                    $this.css('cursor', data.originalCursor);
                }
                $this.data(pluginName, null);
            });
        }
    };
    // *******************************
    // ***** Fin: Public Methods *****
    // *******************************

    // *****************************
    // ***** Start: Supervisor *****
    // *****************************
    $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.' + pluginName );
        }
    };
    // ***************************
    // ***** Fin: Supervisor *****
    // ***************************
})(jQuery);
```

And here's a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7z6by3o3/1/show/)**.

**Edit**

Here's an attempt at explaining the fisheye (barrel distortion) calculations ...

- Starting with a blank lens of `w x h` pixels.
- The code loops through all pixels (target pixels).
- For each target pixel, chooses a pixel (source pixel) from the background image.
- The source pixel is always selected from those on (or close to) the same radial ray as the target, but at a smaller radial distance (using a formula for barrel distortion) from the lens's center.
- This is mechanised by calculation of the polar coordinates `(nr, theta)` of the source pixel, then the application a standard math formula for converting polar back to rectangular coordinates `nxn = nr * Math.cos(theta)` and `nxn = nr * Math.sin(theta)`. Up to this point, all calculations have been made in normalised -1...0...1 space.
- The rest of the code in the block denormaises (rescales), and (the bit I had to heavily adapt) actually implements the source to target pixel mapping by indexing into the 1-dimensional source and target data.

Comment: Known bug: the 'size' option must be even. Odd values give a really  odd effect.

Comment: to make transparent i think all you have to do is to do nothing. Like not draw. And since there is alredy bg underneath drawn beforehand. It will result in same thing..

Comment: can you explain what happens conceptually after inside the circle part. Like why angle is being calculated.

Comment: @Muhammad, ok, you asked for it .... see my edit.

Comment: actually no..what is radial ray, why are you converting to polar coordinates, what's barrel distortion, why did you normalize to -1 to 1. So yea these are questions that i can't seem to get around..Thanks again if you answer, otherwise..ill have a deep look at it in some weeks.

Comment: MuU, (1) "radial ray" == "spoke in virtual bicycle wheel"; (2) polar coordinates are not absolutely necessary, that's just one way to do the necessary calcs - a more efficient solution is available based on congruent triangles (less trig); (3) normalisation makes the calcs simpler - the benefits outweigh the overhead of normalising/denormalisig.

Comment: And barrel distortion is the proper name for the fisheye effect.

Comment: BTW, I knew none of this 2 days ago when I picked up this question. Everything now I know comes from studying the code and googling a couple of searches.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - doesn't work any more?

Comment: @ashleedawg, I am aware. The source image is no longer avaialble. You should be ale to get it working locally, with a local image, though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hftz4gb9/

Comment: still too high IQ and beautiful

Answer (score 1):

You have the center `x0, y0` and the radius `r`.  Basically you need the parametric equation of circle:

`x = x0 + r * cos(t)
y = y0 + r * sin(t)`

Where `t` is the angle between a radial segment and normalized x-axis, and you need to divide it up as needed. For example for your four points case you do

`360/4 = 90`

and so use 0, 90, 180, 270 to get the four points.

Comment: this would only work if radius is 2 px. which would have 4 points.

Comment: As I understand the question, this is the right approach.

Comment: Can you not do 360/n, where n is whatever number of points you are looking for? I explained with n=4 as an example.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer have you tried it? I can't claim to know what visual effect you are going for. I'm just answering your original question of how to draw circles with controlled number of points.

Comment: how would i calculate n. n needs to be big enough so dots don't have space in bteween them and don't overlap over a same pixel.

Comment: this just gives me x,y coordinate, which is fine, but i need to know angle. For small circle that is only 2px in radius it need to only worry about angle 0, 90, 180, 270. 4 pixels. etc