# How to animate gauge in regards to increasing/decreasing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

***Functionality:***

Canvas Gauge is to animate in regards to the increasing/ decreasing value that is calculated and displayed on the browser page. Hence, if there is a counter function, the canvas gauge should animate in regards to the decreasing counter value.

***What I have done:***

I have created out the canvas of 2 gauges as well as the functional implementation of the countdown counter as well as the scroll speed.

***Issue:***

I have correctly created the canvas of 2 gauges as well as the functional implementation. However, they are currently 2 separate entities. ***Hence, I would like to ask for ideas or help, how am I able to integrate both together such that, the canvas gauge is reflecting correctly in regards to increasing/decreasing value of either the speed or countdown counter functions? An example would be the kind of animation as seen in [Attractive-jQuery-Circular-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-TimeCircles/](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Attractive-jQuery-Circular-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-TimeCircles/)***

I have included the code for your perusal:

```js
var numOfSpin = 0,
  distanceCovered = 0,
  counter = 0,
  timer = 10;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//CountDown Counter
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("Counter");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
//dimensions
//Speedometer
var W = canvas.width;
var H = canvas.height;
//CountDown Counter
var W2 = canvas2.width;
var H2 = canvas2.height;
//Global Variables
var degrees = 0;
var new_degrees = 0;
var difference = 0;
var color = "#ffa500";
var bgcolor = "#654321";
var animation_loop, redraw_loop;

function drawGauge() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  //Background 360 degree arc
  //Speedometer
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
  ctx.lineWidth = 30;
  //background arc of the speedometer
  ctx.arc(W / 2, H / 2, 120, 2.35, 0.8, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  //CountDown Counter
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
  ctx2.lineWidth = 30;
  //background arc of the countdown counter
  ctx2.arc(W / 2, H / 2, 120, 2.35, 0.8, false);
  ctx2.stroke();
  //internal gauge will be a simple arc
  //Angle in radians = angle in degrees * PI / 180
  var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
  //Speedometer
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth = 30;
  /* arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)*/
  ctx.arc(W / 2, H / 2, 120, 0 + 135 * Math.PI / 180, radians - 84 * Math.PI / 180, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  //CountDown Counter
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx2.lineWidth = 30;
  /*ctx2.arc(W2/2, H2/2, 100, 0 + 135*Math.PI/180, radians - 84*Math.PI/180, false);*/
  ctx2.arc(W2 / 2, H2 / 2, 120, 0 + 135 * Math.PI / 180, radians - 84 * Math.PI / 180, false);
  ctx2.stroke();
}

function animate() {
  ..(SHOULD I HAVE A SEPARATE FUNCTION FOR THE ANIMATION OR COULD I PLACE IT DIRECTLY UNDER FUNCTION DRAW() ? ? ? )..
}

function MainGame() {

  $("#scrollerDiv").scroll(function() {
    var height = $("#scrollerDiv").scrollTop();
    for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
      if (height > i * 10) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < 10) {
          $("#roller").attr("src", "Image/rolling_pin/Rolling Pin Spin00" + i + ".png");
        }
        if (i >= 10 && i < 100) {
          $("#roller").attr("src", "Image/rolling_pin/Rolling Pin Spin0" + i + ".png");
        }
        if (i >= 100 && i < 1000) {
          $("#roller").attr("src", "Image/rolling_pin/Rolling Pin Spin" + i + ".png");
          $("#scrollerDiv").scrollTop(0);
          numOfSpin++;
          distanceCovered += 0.59;
          console.log(distanceCovered);
          console.log(numOfSpin);
        }
      }
    }
  })

  rollingInterval = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    timer = timer - 1;
    speed = distanceCovered / counter;
    speed2dec = speed.toFixed(2);
    $('#speedSpan').html(speed2dec + '<br>ms');
    $('#timeSpan').html(timer + 's');

    //Set Conditional Checks; user satisfy game condition, advance to next page, else navigate to the "GameOver" Page.
    if (counter == 10 && speed > 20) {
      console.log("Count");
      clearInterval(rollingInterval);
      $("#page2").hide();
      $("#page3").show();
    } else if (counter == 10 && speed < 20) {
      clearInterval(rollingInterval);
      $("#page2").hide();
      $("#GameOver").show();
    }
  }, 1000)

}
```

```html
<div id="page2" class="img-wrapper" align="center" style=" position: relative; background-image: url(Image/Page2.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; width: 100%;height: 100%;">

  <div id='content'></div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="Counter" width="300" height="300">
  </canvas>
  <p id="speedSpan">0.00
    <br>ms</p>
  <p id="timeSpan">10 s</p>

  <img id="roller" style="position: relative; top:1100px; width: 100%" src="Image/rolling_pin/Rolling Pin Spin000.png" />
  <img id="scroll" style="position:absolute; top: 1250px; left: 380px; overflow-y: auto;" src="Image/Scroll.png">

  <div id="scrollerDiv">
    <p id="invisibleElement"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what is wanted. Are you trying to avoid code repetition in writing your two gauges?

Comment: @Roamer-1888   I am trying to set the gauge to animate in accordance to the decreasing value of the counter and also for the second gauge to animate in accordance to increasing or decreasing value of the speed. Picture speedometer.

Comment: You might like to look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26793597/3478010). The code is extensive but essentially animates a canvas overlaid on a background canvas. For a gauge, I'm sure the code will be significantly simpler and the `animate()` function possibly identical.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks!!I would like to ask a few questions in regards to the answer that you have suggested. I would like to know, where did you declare 'this' and also how did you set the plugin name?

Comment: "Where did you declare 'this'?" With jQuery plugins and other involved javascript, it's vital to understand that `this` is dynamic. It's not "declared" but determined at runtime where a function is called. [This article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/) provides a pretty clear explanation of "this" along with the closely related issue of "closure". In my plugin, you will see that `.bind()`, `.call()` and `.apply()` are used quite liberally in order to pass `this` through from function to function.

Comment: "How did you set the plugin name?" Plugin name is defined at the very top of the plugin, `var pluginName = 'canvasLens';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of hours to have a go at this. To keep it simple, I implemented it as a js constructor, `Gauge()` rather than a jQuery plugin.

```
function Gauge(canvasId, options) {
    this.settings = {
        val: 0,
        color: '#FFF',
        bgcolor: '#040',
        lineWidth: 10,
        needleSpan: 5,
        legend: '',
        font: 'Arial',
        fontSize: '12px',
        transitionDuration: '0.7s'
    }
    $.extend(this.settings, options);
    var $canvas = $('#' + canvasId);
    this.ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    this.W = $canvas.width();
    this.H = $canvas.height();
    var offset = $canvas.offset();
    var n = this.settings.needleSpan * Math.PI/180; //needle arc in radians
    var textOffset = parseInt(this.settings.fontSize) / 3;

    //Background 360 degree arc
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.settings.bgcolor;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = this.settings.lineWidth;
    //background circle
    /* arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)*/
    this.ctx.arc(this.W/2, this.H/2, (this.W - this.settings.lineWidth)/2, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    this.ctx.stroke();

    this.ctx.font = this.settings.fontSize + ' ' + this.settings.font;
    this.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    this.ctx.fillText(this.settings.legend, this.W/2, this.H/2 + textOffset);

    // overlaid canvas for the gauge setting
    this.overlay = $("<canvas/>").attr({
        'width': this.W,
        'height': this.H
    }).css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': offset.left,
        'top': offset.top,
        'borderRadius': this.W/2 + 'px',
        'transition-duration': this.settings.transitionDuration
    }).insertAfter($canvas);
    this.ctx2 = this.overlay[0].getContext('2d'); // gauge's setting arc
    this.ctx2.beginPath();
    this.ctx2.strokeStyle = this.settings.color;
    this.ctx2.lineWidth = this.settings.lineWidth;
    /* arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)*/
    this.ctx2.arc(this.W/2, this.H/2, (this.W - this.settings.lineWidth)/2, -Math.PI/2-n/2, -Math.PI/2+n/2, false);
    this.ctx2.stroke();

    this.set(this.settings.val);
}

Gauge.prototype.set = function (val) { // val is an angle in degrees
    this.val = val;
    this.overlay.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + val + 'deg)'
    });
};
Gauge.prototype.get = function () {
    return this.val;
};

$(function() {
    var gauge1 = new Gauge('gauge1', {
        val: 270,
        color: "#009090",
        bgcolor: "#00F5F0",
        needleSpan: 10,
        lineWidth: 10,
        legend: 'Gauge 1',
        font: 'Arial',
        fontSize: '15px'
    });
    var gauge2 = new Gauge('gauge2', {
        val: 90,
        color: "#FFA500",
        bgcolor: "#654321",
        needleSpan: 10,
        lineWidth: 10,
        legend: 'Gauge 2',
        font: 'Arial',
        fontSize: '11px'
    });
    $("#val1").val(gauge1.get()).on('change', function() {
        gauge1.set($(this).val());
    });
    $("#val2").val(gauge2.get()).on('change', function() {
        gauge2.set($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Default settings are defined in the object `this.settings`. Any of the settings can be overridden by passing an `options` object with the same properties as `this.settings`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f8vrmth/2/)

The `input` elements are included to demonstrate that the gauges can be programatically set (in degrees). They are not put in place by the `Gauge()` constructor.

*Tested in Opera 33.0, Chrome 46.0, IE 11*

---

**Note:** as it stands, Gauge() is very raw. Improvements might include :

- Tickmarks/legends on the background dial
- Zero and max limits (ie not use the full 360 degrees)
- Set by real-world value, not degrees
- Text representation of current value inside/outside the circle
- Further styling options

Before embarking on any of that, I would look around for a jQuery plugin. All sorts of very capable gauges and dials already exist.

Comment: Thanks!!I have used another method to solve my issue. Thanks a lot for your help though!!=) much appreciated.

Comment: Luke, no worries, it was fun to write and may be useful to someone else. Out of interest, what method did you choose?

Comment: what I did was to break the drawing of the arc into different functions, one for counter and the other for speedo; e.g `function counterArc(){...(method to draw arc and animate)..}` and 'function SpeedoArc(){...(method to draw arc and animate)..}` and will call the following functions within my `function MainGame(){..}` such that the moving arc will play when the `mainGame()` is called.=)

Comment: OK, separating out into 2 functions is a good idea though for 2 very similar widgets, I would still recommend one constructor function (or jQuery plugin) that can be called with parameters to control the detailed behaviour and appearance.