# Associate an element with a unique number

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm looking for a way to associate a DOM element with a unique number, such that no other element in the DOM will be associated with that number. Obviously, I can't use an `Id` attribute because not all elements have an `Id`.

The most obvious way to do this is to (somehow) acquire a number that will give the element's *position* within the DOM, but I'm not sure if this is feasible. Ultimately, given an arbitrary element from the DOM, I'd like to have a way of mapping that element to a number.

**Everyone is asking why I need to do this -- given a DOM element, I need to use that element as a key in a JS Object. JS Objects must be strings. So, technically, I do not need a unique number, per se, but I need a unique value that can be turned into a "short string" and used as the key in a JS object.**

Comment: Position is not unique. A more important question here is, why would you want to assign an unique id to every single element in DOM? If you really want to do that I would suggest keeping a list of all elements as you generate them.

Comment: There will be nested elements in your `DOM`. How will be the index for them ? Question seems too broad but description does not explain the need to do so. May be there are simple approaches to achieve what you are attempting..

Comment: use a WeakMap to associate an element with another variable without IDs. Only IE has an index...

Comment: you can store the path of childnodes. for example, title, if it were first in the head, would be at `0.0.0`, body at `0.1`, etc. note that you can't modify the dom without re-indexing with this approach.

Comment: @Derek - I never said I wanted to assign a unique id to every single element in the DOM. I said that, given any arbitrary element in the DOM, I would like to generate an number such. that no other element could map to that number.

Comment: @TomBaxter That is the definition of a unique id...

Comment: considering your edit, use a WeakMap(): it's like an object but you can use an element/object for a key instead of just a string. it's really your best bet compared to slow hunt-and-peck iteration or messy dirty checking.

Comment: You need to rethink your data structure. It's too complex.

Comment: @Derek - Yes, potentially, any element will need a unique Id. In reality, only a few elements will need to be uniquely identified. I do not know in advance which elements I will need to identify nor do I know what, if any attributes..... Hey, that gives me an idea.....I can add data- attributes as I need..... and I will be in control of the value, ensuring they are unique.

Comment: you can also use `[].indexOf()` to uniquely hit HTMLElements in an array... so, push in the ones you need to fetch later. you can then store an index or just find them as needed.

Comment: Have you think of using jQuery's `.data` where you can directly associate an object with an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Technically, I do not need a unique number, per se, but I need a unique value that can be turned into a "short string" and used as the key in a JS object.

I see that you have jQuery tagged. This might be a possible solution to your problem. jQuery has a way to associate an element to an object:

```
var ele = /* your element */
$(ele).data({name: "Paul"});

// later you can use the element as a key
$(ele).data();  //returns {name: "Paul"}
```

This will avoid the whole "assigning unique id" mess and just let jQuery does all the hard work for you (creating a map data structure).

---

*Edit by [Roamer-1888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478010/roamer-1888)*

> Basically, I need to "tag" an element uniquely so that if I encounter the same element in the future, I will know I've seen it before. The "tag" value will be the key in my JS object. I will associate various values in the tagged element. I don't want to use Map or WeakMap because they might not be supported on all browsers.

To meet this requirement, you would typically use jQuery's `.data()` as follows :

```
//...
var elementData = $(ele).data('myApplication');
if(!elementData) { // this element was not previously encountered
    elementData = {
        prop_A: ...,
        prop_B: ...,
        prop_C: ...
    };
    $(ele).data('myApplication', elementData);
}
// Here `elementData` is guaranteed to exist and its properties can be read/written.
//...
```

This technique is particularly useful for preseving state in jQuery plugins. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834763/3478010)

Multiple applications/modules can do this without interfering with each other.

Comment: FYI, jQuery's `.data()` assigns a unique ID property to each DOM element in order to track it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, and this will also solve his issue completely.

Comment: Well not completely.  The OP asked for a unique ID to be able to track an element with.  You would still have to add code to coin such an id that you could then store in `.data()` and retrieve from `.data()`.  When you're done, it's not any simpler that not using jQuery as in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 That really depends on how OP is going to use it.

Comment: Yes, it does depend upon how they're going to use it.  I was taking them literally that they want/need a unique ID for other uses.  But, if they really just want to store some state on the object, they could certainly use `.data()` or they could just store the state in a custom property on the DOM element too.

Comment: That is absolutely true.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that there might be a better way to solve your problem if we understood what the real problem was.  But, at any point in time, you can find what position an element is at (if it is currently inserted in the document) with something like this:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

If you needed to then get a unique index for a DOM element (at this particular point in time), you can do so by just searching for it in that HTMLCollection.  It's position in the collection is guaranteed to be a unique index.

But, of course as the DOM is modified, this HTMLCollection will change as will the index.

If you wanted to assign a non-changing unique index, you could just assign a property to each DOM element based on a monotomically increasing counter.

```
var idCntr = 1;
function assignIds() {
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (!items[i]._uniqueId) {
            items[i]._uniqueId = idCntr++;
        }
    }
}
```

You can call this function as many times as you want and it will assign new unique IDs to any DOM elements that don't yet have an id, but will leave ids that were already assigned the same (so they will never change).

---

If you just want to be able to generate a unique ID for any given DOM node such that you can always have the same ID for that DOM node, then you can just again use a monotomically increasing counter.

```
 var idCntr = 1;
 function assignId(elem) {
     if (!elem._uniqueId) {
         elem._uniqueId = idCntr++;
     }
     return elem._uniqueId;
 }
```

You can then call this on any DOM element that you want to assign a unique ID to and it will both assign the id to the element and return the id that it assigned.  If you pass it an element that already has an id, it will leave that id in place and just return it.

---

**Based on your latest edit**, it appears you're just trying to generate an id string that you can use as a key in a JS object.  You can certainly use the above `assignId()` function for that.

In a modern browser, you can also use a Map or a 
WeakMap object which will accept the DOM object itself as the key - you don't need to manufacture your own string key.  You can then look it up directly with the DOM element too (since it's the key).

Comment: wouldn't an attrib work better because you can avoid iterating already-upgraded elements via a clever querySelectorAll() call (maybe with `:not()`)  ? (you don't revisit the live tag collection anyway...)

Comment: @dandavis - Depending upon the details of the actual use case, there are certainly many possible variants.  A data attribute could meet the objective you state.  It isn't clear whether the OP needs to be able "find" a given element with an ID (a weakMap or something that `querySelectorAll()` could use would be useful for that) or whether they just need to be able to "tag" an element uniquely for later identification or comparison in which case an assigned ID is all that is needed (which is more my last example).

Comment: @TomBaxter - In my last couple paragraphs of my answer, I added some info relative to the latest edits you made to your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 -- Basically, I need to "tag" an element uniquely so that if I encounter the same element in the future, I will know I've seen it before. The "tag" value will be the key in my JS object. I will associate various values in the tagged element.

I don't want to use Map or WeakMap because they might not be supported on all browsers.

Comment: @TomBaxter - then my `assignId()` function should work just fine for you.  It assigns a unique ID to any element you want to tag and it retains that tag for the life of the element.